# Choose a basis of $\mathbb{F}_q/\mathbb{Z}_p$ to do inverse quickly.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be the finite field with $q$ elements ($q=p^n$, $p$ is a prime). $\mathbb{F}_q$ can be regarded as a linear space over the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of dimension $n$. The question is:

> How to choose the bases $(\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n)$ and $(\epsilon_1',...,\epsilon_n')$ of $\mathbb{F}_q/\mathbb{Z}_p$, such that for any $(i_1,...,i_n)\in\mathbb{Z}_p^n\backslash\{0\}$, we can quickly determine $(i_1',...,i_n')\in\mathbb{Z}_p^n\backslash\{0\}$, which satisfies
>   $$(i_1\epsilon_1+\cdots+i_n\epsilon_n)(i_1'\epsilon_1'+\cdots+i_n'\epsilon_n')=1.$$

Comment: I think this depends on your definition of *quickly*. Finding the inverse, even in the case of a prime field (so $q=p, n=1$), is one of the things that cryptopeople in particular seek to avoid, because it costs computational resources. Sure, it can be done with generalized Euclid's algorithm, but that is not fast enough in some cases (elliptic curve crypto primitives come to mind). If your $q$ is small (say less than $10^5$ or even $10^6$), then I would use discrete logarithm tables for all $\Bbb{F}_q$ arithmetic.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken no matter what bases you choose, the linear system you need to solve still depends on the element to be inverted, and you have to work for it. This is unlike the case of multiplication, where there are optimized normal bases reducing the workload. At least I'm not aware of anything similar for inversion. Admittedly I'm not an expert on such optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm sure you know this, and probably it is not what you're looking for, but if you represent $\mathbf F_q$ as a quotient $\mathbf F_p[x]/(f)$ for some irreducible polynomial $f$ of degree $n$, then you can simply take
$$
\varepsilon_k=\varepsilon_k'=x^k
$$
for $k=0,\ldots,n-1$,
and determine $i_0',\ldots,i_{n-1}'$ by applying the extended Euclidean algorithm to the polynomial $g=i_0+i_1x+\cdots+i_{n-1}x^{n-1}$ and $f$ in $\mathbf F_p[x]$. You find $a,b\in\mathbf F_p[x]$ such that
$$
af+bg=1
$$
in $\mathbf F_p[x]$. In $\mathbf F_q$ this gives $bg=1$, i.e.
$$
g^{-1}=i_0'+i_1'x+\cdots+i_{n-1}'x^{n-1}=b
$$
in $\mathbf F_q$. This method is very fast, and you only need the Euclidean algorithm.